# Mixed Content iframe Issue In Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, mixed-content

I'm finishing up a Rails 4.2 app for a client and I have enabled the force_ssl option in the production environment. Now everything is working fine but the client NEEDS to embed an iframe that fetches from a non secure page. This non secure page I have no control over and the page doesn't support https.... :/

Is there any solution that would allow me to have SSL enforced everywhere except on this one controller action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I ended up using https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer to setup the SSL constraints I needed:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, except: '/search', strict: true
```

The force_ssl controller class method is great but I actually needed more fine grain control because the page that I needed no security on is actually a user genertaed page in a CMS controller. So I actually just can't exclude an action but an actual user generated URL. I know this may sound odd but it's working perfect for my weird situation. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a unique action throughout the controller hierarchy you can exclude this one.

```
class ApplicationController
  force_ssl except :unique_action_name

end
```

See the [reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html) for further information.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help but I decided to use some rack middle ware to allow me to add constraints which worked out nicer for my requirements. Thanks again though! :)